# App that uses default camera to save in a non-default location

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, camera, nexus-5, automation

I am looking for an application that does the above. Preferably, I could create application shortcuts for different save locations.

Also, a Dropbox option would be nice but not required since I could use DropSync.

Answer (score 1):

I use [FolderMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.fmount) (needs root) as a workaround to this issue. I create a link of the folder where the camera images are stored to a different folder in the external SD card.

> Today some apps store big files over the internal SD card (e.g. games,
>   podcasts, offline RSS content, pictures, videos, offline navigation
>   software). Typically users have a small internal sd card size (~16GB)
>   while the external SD is a lot bigger (~32-64GB). Most of these apps
>   users download from the Play Store save their application data in the
>   internal sdcard by default and don't have an option to use the
>   external SD card to store data so they starve your internal SD card
>   memory. FolderMount is the solution to this issue. **This app has the
>   ability to link folders in your internal sdcard to folders in your
>   external sdcard thereby populating the internal sdcard folders with
>   content that really exists in the external card.** This helps us free
>   space and have multiple games/apps with big data stored simultaneously
>   without the need to uninstall. For Nexus devices with no external
>   sdcard, this application should help link folders to a usb flash drive
>   for example.

Comment: Yep works great - I'm running Cyanogenmod 11